# Finding the order of an intersection of proper subgroups.

Tags: group-theory

**Q:** Let $H,K$ be proper subgroups of a group $G$. If $|K|=18$ and $|H|=24$, what are the possible orders of $K\cap H$?

**Thoughts**: $|H|$ and $|K|$ are finite, so by Lagrange's Theorem, $18 \bigm| |G|$ and $24 \bigm| |G|$, thus $lcm(18,24)=72 \bigm| |G|$, but I don't think that this gets me anywhere.

I am really not sure where to do from here—what is the significance of the intersection of the subgroups?

By a lemma proven by the subgroup criterion, I know that the intersection of subgroups is also a subgroup:

Let $(H_i)_{i \in I}$ be a collection of subgroups of G where $I$ is an index set (possibly infinite).
$\implies \bigcap_{i\in I} H_i$ is a subgroup.

**Proof**:
$H_i ≤ G \iff \forall a_i b_i \in H_i, a_i^{-1} b_i \in H_i.$ Take $a,b \in \bigcap_{i \in I}H_i \implies a^{-1},b \in \bigcap_{i \in I} H_i \\\blacksquare$
However, it seems to me that this proof assumes that all the subgroups are not disjoint, because if they were, then wouldn’t $H \cap K = \{0, •\}$?

How do I know that in my question above that $H$ and $K$ are not disjoint?

Comment: Did you mean to write $|K|  = 18$?

Comment: Yes, fixed it sorry.

Comment: Great. Lagrange's theorem is the right tool here, but you're not applying it to the appropriate group (especially because $G$ is not finite by hypothesis). Instead, try thinking about the fact that $K \cap H$ is a subgroup of both $K$ and $H$.

Comment: Ok, I also added the bit about my confusion with intersection of subgroups part.

Comment: $H$ and $K$ can never be disjoint, because the both contain the identity of $G$. It is certainly possible that the intersection of $H$ and $K$ is trivial. Why does this worry you?

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: But, in this question, $K$ and $H$ are strict subgroups — does this mean that $K \cap H < G$? I'm not sure what 'strict subgroup' really implies

Comment: Strict only means here that we can't have equality. And of course, $K\cap H=G$ with $K,H\subset G$ would implies $H=K=G$, a contradiction to $H,K$ *strict* subgroups of $G$.

Comment: By Lagrange's theorem, the *possible* orders of $H\cap K$ are the *common* factors of $|H|$ and $|K|$, namely: $1$, $2$, $3$ and $6$. This is because $H\cap K\le H$ and $H\cap K\le K$. It doesn't matter what $|G|$ actually is.

Comment: @Devo It does matter to some extent. For example, if $|G|=72$, that forces $|H\cap K|=6$. But here there are no restrictions on $|G|$ so all common divisors are possible.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $H\leq G$ and $K\leq G$ implies that $H\cap K\leq G$, $H\cap K\leq H$, $H\cap K\leq K$ (why?).

Thus, if $n=|H\cap K|$, we are looking for $n$ such that $n\mid |G|, n\mid |H|, n\mid |K|$. Since $|H|$ and $|K|$ both divide $|G|$, we have that $n\mid |G|$ automatically. So then, you are just looking for the common factors of $|H|$ and $|K|$.

Also, to answer your last question, $H\cap K\neq \emptyset$ since $1\in H\cap K$.